# Retrieve single name and multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement in my app which has multiple members and single name.In my web app i need to create a groups of some users.So suppose there are 2 groups test1 and test2.test1 group has 1 and 2 members and test2 has members 1,2 and 3(1 or 2 or 3 are not numbers consider them as group memebers.

My web app has 2 columns.if retrieve `select * from groups` then the output is like the following

```
groupname      groupMembers
test1           1
test1           2
test2           1 
test2           2 
test2           3
```

but I want output like this

```
 groupname      groupMembers
    test1           1
                    2
                    1 
    test2           2 
                    3
```

So is it possible using any sql query.i am using jdbc for retrieving from mysql.

this is sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4610/1

Comment: That's not possible in a single query.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you really want to get a row with a NULL groupname and guess its contents by looking at all previous rows? Or do you want to create a tree structure for display? The proper place to do result formatting is in the web application anyway, not on the database layer

Comment: @fonini multiple queries are also acceptable

Comment: Perhaps you should post another question on how to create tree structures in whatever language you are using, or in Javascript. What you are asking makes little sense in SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well I need to show the output as showed in the post.please tell me is it possible to using sql

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the answer given by T0to will be I think.I get the 2nd coulmns as comma(,) separated .So I can split using ,

Comment: Or, in a properly design database, you could read the groupnames from `group`, and the member IDs from some table called `member` or `groupmembers` that would contain the GroupID and the MemberIDs. Why is there a `GroupMembers` column in the `groups` table?

Comment: Can you please give me a fiddle and Please post this as an answer so that i can upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that:

```
select name, GROUP_CONCAT(age) from groups group by name;
```

That's not exactly the ouput you want but i hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for answering.though the answer is not exactly to the question but It is helpful +1

Comment: if there are more than 2 coulmns then how will I do.Suppose age,city,country is also there then please tell me how to do?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do if there are multiple columns http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8899b/1